# CSS ID and Class

Tags: css

I am trying to make a **dropdown** menu in CSS, managed to get something working with my code but I want to make the line height of the items in the dropdown narrower but it isn't doing anything when I change the line-height attribute in `.dropdown-content`, it defaults to the line height of the main `#navigation id`.

**CSS code:**

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #004B60;
    width: 180px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 0px 0px;
    top:100%;
    z-index:1;
    height:380px; 
    line-height:5px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#fff; 
    padding:0 15px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

#navigation { float:right; white-space:nowrap; }
#navigation ul{ list-style-type: none; height:20px; font-weight: bold; float:left;}
#navigation ul li{ float:left; display:inline; }
#navigation ul li a{ float:left; height:64px; line-height:64px; text-decoration: none; color:#fff; padding:0 15px;}
#navigation ul li a.active,
#navigation ul li a:hover{ background:#fff; color:#8b0000; }
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.asp" <%if scr = "index.asp" then%> class="active" <%    end if%>>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp" <%if scr = "about.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>About Us</a></li>
        <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="products.asp" <%if scr = "products.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Products</a>                           
                <div class="dropdown-content">

                    <P><a href="products.ASP">Item1</a></P>
                    <P><a href="products.ASP">Item2</a></P>                                 
                    <P><a href="products.ASP">Item3</a></P>
                    <P><a href="products.ASP">Item4</a></P>
                    <P><a href="products.ASP">Item5</a></P>
                </div>
            </div>
            <li><a href="shipping.asp" <%if scr = "shipping.asp" then%>class="active" <%end if%>>Shipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="returns.asp" <%if scr = "returns.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Returns</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonials.asp"<%if scr = "testimonials.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp" <%if scr = "contact.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Contact</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what does firebug say about it?

Comment: fierbug is a plug in for firefox that you can use to open up and analyse your page and it will tell you all applied CSS rules as well as what order they apply and which rules overwrite other rules. It's extremely useful. It also does a host of other things such as script analysis. Recommended. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: <P><a href="products.ASP">Item1</a></P> the P for Paragraph should be in lower case <p>

Comment: Your #nav css comes after your .dropdown-content in the css file thus over-riding it -- order matters, that is the cascading part of cascading style sheet

Comment: Still the same result doing this

Comment: You're missing a closing `</li`> after the closing `</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem here it's in

```
#navigation ul li a {
   height:64px; 
   line-height:64px;
}
```

here is the solution

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #004B60;
  width: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 0px 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 380px;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
#navigation {
  float: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}
#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
#navigation ul li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
#navigation ul li a.active,
#navigation ul li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #8b0000;
}
/*Add code*/

#navigation ul li a {
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.asp" <%if scr="index.asp" then%> class="active" <%    end if%>>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.asp" <%if scr="about.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="products.asp" <%if scr="products.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Products</a> 
        <div class="dropdown-content">

          <P><a href="products.ASP">Item1</a>
          </P>
          <P><a href="products.ASP">Item2</a>
          </P>
          <P><a href="products.ASP">Item3</a>
          </P>
          <P><a href="products.ASP">Item4</a>
          </P>
          <P><a href="products.ASP">Item5</a>
          </P>
        </div>
      </div>
      <li><a href="shipping.asp" <%if scr="shipping.asp" then%>class="active" <%end if%>>Shipping</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="returns.asp" <%if scr="returns.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Returns</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.asp" <%if scr="testimonials.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp" <%if scr="contact.asp" then%> class="active" <%end if%>>Contact</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need any other help

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are modifying the element `<div id="navigation">`and all of links ("a") inside it. As `<div class="dropdown-content">` is inside `<div id="navigation">` it will be modified too.

I would suggest you two solutions:

1. Put `<div class="dropdown-content">` outside `<div id="navigation">`
2. Modify `<div class="dropdown-content">` in your CSS file using the !important notation, ie.: `dropdown-content{ line-height: 30 !important;}` so it would overwrite the `#navigation` style.

Comment: Thank you - tired option 2 this didn't work. Tried option 1 - kind of works but this moves the products right to the end of the menu, not sitting inbetween about and shipping.

Comment: I just tried using this code `.dropdown-content a {
  line-height: 30px !important;
  padding: 5px !important;
}` 
The result is in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ldepaula/vmsu23ww/2/

Please, check if this is what you expected to happen because I couldn't quite understand your question.

Comment: You mean my answer is option 2?